# Sharepoint always down on the weekend?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

For some reason, our sharepoint site always goes down on Saturday. It's the stangest thing and I can't figure out why. I'm a total noob at sharepoint and have been thrown into being the go to guy for sharepoint with my current employer.

I've tried bouncing IIS on Fridays to see if there is anything I can do before hand.

Is there anything that might be scheduled that I may not know about that would cause sharepoint to go down?

Remember I'm a total noob as sharepoint.

Thanks to all that reply.

Edit: Also this our front-end and database instances are on virtual servers.

Comment: You should try ask this question on sister site http://serverfault.com/

Comment: No offence Mr Gambler but I am puzzled as to why this question has so many up votes. Its not programming related (aka better on serverfault) and you've provided virtually no info - for example what exactly does 'going down' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing, in general, that would make SharePoint go down over the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I would check all of the event logs on all servers in the farms to see if anything is happening that might be causing it to go down.

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate on "going down"? It could be SQL Server going down, or IIS, or the App Pool, or the WebApp itself. Is it just incredibly slow/unresponsive the first time you access it after the weekend? If so then you may need to schedule a wakeup script to run, i.e. http://spwakeup.codeplex.com/Wikipage

Answer (score 1):

You can also check your SharePoint log files that are located in the

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\LOGS

folder.

I have also seen some very odd behavior if SQL log files are getting filled on a dbase server.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint just needs the weekends to relax